# php file creation and how to run my php program

Tags: php, netbeans, wampserver

I'd like if someone could give me some advice on creating the php file, i know to php language.but where to write it.i have followed some tutorial to run php file in netbeans but its pathethic to download xamp server,apache http server.can u give me the direct of how make configuration and all.i have window7 ultimate and will file i hav to download i don't know. i have netbeans all bundle feature and wamp server.how should i write my php program successfully.plz help me to resolve this.

i m editing the question becoz in comment it is than wordspace given there thatwhy not accepting

thanks its working..
can u tell me why this code doesnot work properly
my php code(or content is this)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Binary Search</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        h1 {color: blue}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center">Computer guess number by using binary search</h1>
<form method="GET">
<?
if (empty($flag_num))
{
    $flag_num = -1;
}
if ($flag_num==-1)
{
if (empty($max_num)) $max_num = -1;
if (empty($min_num)) $min_num = -1;
$flag_num = 1;
print <<<Here
<input type="hidden" name="flag_num" value="$flag_num">
<input type="hidden" name="max_num" value="$max_num">
<input type="hidden" name="min_num" value="$min_num">
Input your hidden number: <input type="text" name="hid_num" value="$hid_num"> (1-99)
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Now let's computer guess">
Here;
}
else 
{
if ($max_num==-1 && $min_num==-1)
{
    $max_num = 100;
    $min_num = 0;
    $result_num = $hid_num;
}
else 
{
    if ($comparision == "bigger")
    {
        $min_num = $guess_num;  
    }
    else if ($comparision == "smaller")
    {
        $max_num = $guess_num;  
    }
}
$guess_num = ($max_num + $min_num)/2;
setType($guess_num,"integer");
print "Computer guess <h3> $guess_num </h3>";
if ($guess_num == $result_num)
{
    $flag_num = -1;
}
if ($flag_num == -1)
{
    print <<<Here
<input type="hidden" name="flag_num" value="$flag_num">
<h1> Congratulation, Computer win </h1>
<input type="submit" value="Next>>>" >
Here;
}
else 
{
    print <<<Here
<input type="hidden" name="flag_num" value="$flag_num">
<input type="hidden" name="max_num" value="$max_num">
<input type="hidden" name="min_num" value="$min_num">
<input type="hidden" name="guess_num" value="$guess_num">
<input type="hidden" name="result_num" value="$result_num">
<br>
Your intruction: <input type="radio" name="comparision" value="bigger"> Bigger
                 <input type="radio" name="comparision" value="smaller"> Smaller
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
Here;
}
}
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

it doesnot giving the output properly as required

Comment: this post is oddly formatted, contains no grammar or spelling, and calls downloading XAMP "pathetic"... not to mention the tutorial he is referencing gives a step by step process (I know because I've used it) to do the entire tutorial - hence my downvote

Comment: Grammar or spelling shouldn't stop one from asking questions. Upvoted to rescue.

Comment: You should post a new question instead of updating this one.

Comment: Downvoted because the question is so poorly worded/formatted that it is unclear what is being asked.  Sorry user2162112 and Nirmal, but that is the criteria for downvoting.  BTW, user2162112 you indicated in comments that the answers were helpful - please consider marking one as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wherever wamp is installed go to the folder "www", put the the php file there

then go to localhost:8080/yourfile.php

that's all there is to it

Answer (score 1):

You could write PHP code in almost anything, and the file will be *created* as long as you add the `.php` extension to the new file. I wrote a few simple programs using Notepad and [**Notepad++**](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) before going onto [**Eclipse PDT**](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/).

To run your file, one out of *many* ways, you can start up your WAMPserver, browse to `http://localhost` and drag and drop your file into the browser.

You could also put the `.php` file inside the ***www*** folder (*IIRC thats the name of the folder, my memory is a bit hazy*) and then browse to `http://localhost/name_of_file.php`. In either case, if successful, your PHP code should execute on the page.

Comment: ok.i have installed the wamp server.make a php file and added with extention.php.now in the wamp server i hav started the all services.now what i do i m not getting

Comment: open up your browser, go to `localhost` and drag and drop the file. Easiest thing is to have a file with `<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>` and see if it displays the information.

Comment: @user216116: Also, given by your previous questions you should start to mark answers as accepted so other people with the same problems know what solved your issue.

Comment: i m tried to drag the file but afer dragging the file the dialog box automatticaly open and option come to save and open as we are downloading something.what should i du??